# Passing muliple options to controller in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm trying to send multiple selected options to my controller but i can't

## Code

`route`

```
Route::post('/spacssendto/{id}', 'ProductController@spacssendto')->name('spacssendto');
```

`ajax`

```
$("body").on("click", ".sendspacsdatato", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
 var id = $("#product_id").val();
 $.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: '{{ url('admin/spacssendto') }}/'+encodeURI(id),
  data: {
    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
    'product_id': $('#product_id').val(),
    'subspecification_id': $('.subspecifications').val(),
 },
   success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
   },
   error: function (data) {
    alert(data);
   }
  });
});
```

`controller`

```
public function spacssendto(Request $request, $id) {
      dd($request->all());
}
```

`my form (output)`

```
<form method="POST" action="http://sieffgsa.pp/admin/products/15" accept-charset="UTF-8">

    <input name="_token" value="DLrcOa0eOm90e4aaGSYp2uCeiuKtbGCT9fCOUP16" type="hidden">
    <input name="product_id" id="product_id" value="15" type="hidden">

    <div class="col-md-4">ram</div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="subspecifications form-control tagsselector" id="subspecifications" name="subspecifications[]" multiple="multiple">

            <option value="3">2gig</option>
            <option value="4">4gig</option>

        </select>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">

        <label for="">Actions</label><br>
        <button type="button" id="sendspacsdatato" class=" sendspacsdatato btn btn-xs btn-success">Save</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

> PS: This form printed by Ajax in my view so it means there is several
>   more forms involved (the same way) that's why i mostly used classes
>   and not id's. Yet when I hit save button I will get 3 times repeat in
>   network (if i have 3 form)

## Errors

1. Error 500 in network
2. dd result:

   array:3 [
     "_token" => "DLrcOa0eOm90e4aaGSYp2uCeiuKtbGCT9fCOUP16"
     "product_id" => "15"
     "subspecification_id" => null
   ]

[image: one]

## Question

1. How can I pass my multiple options (selected) to controller?

## UPDATE

Thanks to `Seva Kalashnikov` I fixed the problem just for helping others I'll publish final results here so you can have full code, hope it helps.

`javascript`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".sendspacsdatato", function(e){
      var form = $(this).closest('form');
      var id = form.find('input[name="product_id"]').val();
      // e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '{{ url('admin/spacssendto') }}',
        data: {
          '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
          'product_id': id,
          'subspecifications': $(this).closest('form').find('select.subspecifications').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
          alert('Specifications added successfully.').fadeIn().delay(6000).fadeOut();
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log('Error!');
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

`controller`

```
public function spacssendto(Request $request) {

  $this->validate($request, array(
      'product_id' => 'required',
      'subspecifications' => 'required',
    ));
    $product = Product::find($request->product_id);
    $product->subspecifications()->sync($request->subspecifications, false);
}
```

Comment: try to serialize() the form instead passing val()

Comment: @Florin how? ...

Comment: $( 'form' ).serialize() ... assuming token is in the form ... else disable the token in laravel ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get `select` with css class `subspecifications` inside the same `form` element

```
'subspecification_id': $(this).closest('form').find('select.subspecifications').val()
```

Try this code:

```
$('.sendspacsdatato').click(function() {

    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    var id = form.find('input[name="product_id"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '{{ url('admin/spacssendto') }}/'+encodeURI(id),
        data: {
            '_token': form.find('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'product_id': id,
            'subspecification_id': form.find('select.subspecifications').val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this gives me something like `"subspecification_id" => array:1 [    0 => "5"  ]` and still i'm getting 3 results in network I should only get 1 result, it seems try to get all my 3 forms at once while i only selected options of 1 of my forms.

Comment: Ok I see, so its different forms in your case, I thought you have a single form for all the rows.. let me change my answer

Comment: See the modified answer

Comment: same goes here.

Comment: i think i need to give some id or... to make each form unique and since all the forms belong to same product i should remove product id from route

Comment: yes, thats another issue, you need unique id's in each form

Comment: ok, i did remove id from route and also with this `'subspecification_id': $('.subspecifications').val(),` i get the same result as your answer. how should i give id to form?

Comment: I assume you have an issue somewhere else, maybe you print this javascript code in a loop or something, you have to troubleshoot

Comment: this is ajax in ajax in ajax :D so i've put it outside of my other ajax success codes and the change is that i only get 1 time error 500 :)) but still error :p

Comment: and oh, i had to use `$("body").on("click", ".sendspacsdatato", function(e){` in order to work

Comment: Thanks bro, I fixed it (without your helps impossible) so I just published final results as update.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!